# Guitar real function which sound then played real guitar

Tags: usb, cableready

Hello I looking for function which show sound on web site on my fretboard guitar actually I have guitar fretboard And I need function which show sound when I played please help me I want create something how rock smith  please help me :)

I expecting answer :)